# Pagination in coldFusion calculating wrong records count while searched data

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, pagination

Working on paginaton Part and Using mysql for the Pagination..

All seems working fine unless i try to filter the results down.

My Current scenario is: i display 12 records on a Page.

here is the breakdown of my data:

```
<cfset per_page = 12>
<cfset start = per_page * page>
<cfset start = start - per_page>

<CFQUERY name="data" datasource="#dsn#">
select *,(select count(*) from u) as totalcount from u, s, v, ut, m where 1=1 
<cfif len(trim(search))>
    <cfset search = trim(htmlEditFormat(lcase(search)))>
     and lower(u.username) like <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#search#%">
</cfif>    
order by u.id 
LIMIT <cfqueryparam value="#start#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />,
<cfqueryparam value="#per_page#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />
</CFQUERY>

<cfset count = val(data.recordcount)>
  <cfset paginationNumbers = Round(count / per_page)>
```

When there is a search, the pagination still shows, while i want to hide it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um... when you say "the pagination still shows" do you mean the `LIMIT` part of the SQL statement is still sent to the DB?

If so, well it would be. You're conditional regarding whether it's a search or not is only around the `WHERE` filter clause, not around the `LIMIT` clause. You need to have it around both.

If it's not that you're asking, I don't really follow what you're saying. Perhaps don't be so economical with your wording.

Comment: i had already added for coldfusion also for the same php version, but there seems to be an issue in coldfusion code i wrote

Comment: @Jangun, I did see that other question. I agreed with all the people who downvoted it and would have voted to close it myself, had others not already done so.

Comment: agreed, that's fine, well at least i tried to solve, but i am facing issue, still can't get past as no one is guiding, no harsh words, but i have seen in stackoverflow, people never try to convert and answers are just provided, well are they lucky enough and i am on the verge of the hill to be fallen as i did tried to code, even that might having issue at multiple places

Comment: The problem is your question shows very little effort to do it yourself, which is kinda a requirement on Stack Overflow. And it's a good requirement. And having been advised of that, you didn't then really update your question, so I don't know what you expect. Stack Overflow isn't a charity. It's a Q&A site, and the quality and type of questions have to be such that there's benefit to future visitors. It's not simply about solving *your* problems, it's about providing answers to problems anyone might have. So converting situation-specific code isn't really suitable.

Comment: did you looked at the question below update #1, i had added both codes, php one and coldfusion one, i converted thewhole script and posted on pastebin

Comment: did you looked at the question below update #1, i had added both codes, php one and coldfusion one, i converted thewhole script and posted on pastebin

Comment: As I said: "So converting situation-specific code isn't really suitable." "Convert my code for me"/"be a syntax error checker for me" isn't what Stack Overflow is about. Ask yourself this: how does your question benefit *anyone* other than you? It doesn't does it? No. So it's not appropriate for Stack Overflow. This won't change no matter how often you ask. Plus you're just being  lazy: the question you're asking about is a syntax error, & the error message will tell you the line that it's happening on, & it's very obvious what it is if you *just look*. Ppl have no patience for laziness here.

Comment: oh god, please please please do not give me lectures. You do not want to guide, no issues, go and play with your children's, cheers :)

Comment: I'm not lecturing you. I'm explaining why your question isn't appropriate for Stack Overflow, and accordingly why everyone has *told* you this. Just because you'd prefer it to not be that way doesn't mean the situations changes! So there's no point in getting ansty about it: I know it's not what you want to hear, but... well... *so be it*. Surely this is not the first time in your life you have accidentally done something wrong? Why are you getting so uppity about it? Sh*t happens. Move on.

Comment: well Adam, I do not want to say here or upset the forum, but you know what i mean for you, Thanks

Comment: Why are you blaming *me* for this? I'm just articulating the general approach on S/O, and I'm only doing that because you seem to not understand it. But this is not my site, so I do not make the rules (nor, actually, do I agree with them, but that's neither here nor there). Seriously, I think you should be doing a bit of introspection here and ask yourself why you're getting snippy at me.

Comment: Jangun, I think you are confusing StackOverflow with a more traditional forum. This is a moderated Q&A site, where the questions asked are issues that will likely be encountered by multiple people and the answers will provide ongoing benefit.  As @AdamCameron stated, it is ***not*** a code translation service.  It is ***not*** a code review service (that would be http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  You might have more success on http://www.houseoffusion.com/, or https://forums.adobe.com/community/coldfusion.

Comment: If you haven't already, you might take the StackOverflow Tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour.  In particular, take note of the section titled "Get answers to practical, detailed questions".